# Landsat 8 image very poor in QGIS

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

I am trying to download an image from Google Earth by uploading a shapefile. This shapefile is basically a small town in Mexico. The code I am using is as follows:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
 .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')
 .filterBounds(table)
 .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
 .first()
 .clip(table)

var viz = {bands:['B4','B3','B2'],min :0,max:3000,gamma:1.4}
Map.addLayer(image,viz,'Layer1')
image = image.toUint16();


Export.image.toDrive({
  image:image.select(['B4','B3','B2']),
  description: 'Ageb40087',
  scale: 30,
  region: table,
  maxPixels : 10e11,
  fileDimensions : 7680,
  //crs : 'EPSG:32643'
})
```

var tablw has the following properties:

```
type: FeatureCollection
id: projects/ee-my-prernam/assets/feat_40087
version: 1667920774256353
columns: Object (2 properties)
properties: Object (1 property)
```

When I download the file and open in QGIS, it looks really poor:
[image]

The following are the QGIS parameters:
[image]

How can I better visualize this image? Or it is something wrong with the download parameters?

Comment: Try and download a larger area see the difference. If you want to see some spatial patterns in your image, then probably Landsat's spatial resolution is too coarse

Comment: As Nikos says, the cell size is fixed so you will not get any more detail at that scale. You may be able to make the colours a little more meaningful by experimenting with the **Min / Max Value Settings**, or by setting the limits manually for each band.

Comment: Thanks Matt and Nikos. Is there anyway I can adjust the scale, as in maybe zoom out a little bit?